# Can't remove certain fonts in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fonts, process-explorer

We have an x64 Windows 7 professional machine on which some but not all fonts can not be removed. The problematic fonts in question are not [system fonts](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/product.aspx?pid=161) or [Microsoft Office fonts](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/product.aspx#Office) (I think, they haven't updated the list for Office2010).  One example: [StoneSansOSITC TT](http://www.fonts.com/findfonts/detail.htm?productid=215638) (filename `IT243__.ttf`). Curiously other fonts in the same family could be deleted, about half a dozen.

The error message is something like *"this file is in use and can't be deleted [try again] [skip]"*.

We've tried removing the fonts under a domain account which is member of the local Administrators group as well as the Local Administrator account. We've tried removing from Safe Mode and various combinations of logging off and rebooting.

I used [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to search for the open file handle, and it identifies `csrss.exe` as having that file open, as well as a number of other fonts. I've proved, as the [wikipedia article on csrss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client/Server_Runtime_Subsystem) says, that terminating the process results in a blue screen of death.

How do I track down which application/service/process is causing these files to be in use all the time and shut them down?

**update:**

This person's [similar report](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/b98fc512-8f60-497f-a992-bb6e5baaabe7/) indicates there may be a problem with Windows 7 getting confused over how many typefaces are represented in a font family (thinks there are 4 when actually are 6).

[This thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/30513-cant-delete-font.HTML) has a pic of the error message we see:
[image: font cannot be deleted because it is in use error dialog]

We tried the [Unlocker](http://unlocker.emptyloop.com/) program mentioned [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/57212-deleting-fonts-use-but-not.HTML), and while it identified locked files in the fonts directory they didn't match the ones we were attempting to delete.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found a back door which works, mostly, but there are still some unexplained oddities like Windows thinks the fonts are still installed until a logoff/on cycle is completed, and that if the removed font is later re-installed Windows says the font is already installed, even though it is not displayed in the list. Thankfully applications like Adobe Illustrator see the truth in either case, which is the desired result in any case.

The kludge:

Open two Windows Explorer windows,(for convenience snap them right and left with <kbd>winkey</kbd>-<kbd>left</kbd>,  <kbd>winkey</kbd>-<kbd>right</kbd>.) On one side access the font folder directly, bypassing the confused Control Panel font manager, with `\\machine-name\c$\Windows\Fonts`. On the other navigate to `C:\Windows\Fonts`, which will switch to Font Manager view.

On the FM side, locate each font to be removed, *select > properties* to get the actual filename, and then delete that file from the other explorer window.

[image: remove problem fonts via UNC path]

**Update:** For the C:\Windows\Fonts window, right-click on column heading and you can show the file name (and then click on heading to sort by path!).

[image: details view columns context menu]

Comment: Some fonts may have multiple files (b, z, i, l, etc). You will have to remove all of them to fully uninstall the particular font.

Comment: And for those of us who stupidly managed to download thousands of fonts... good luck.

Comment: You will also need to log in as administrator and remove the registry keys for the corresponding fonts, in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`.

Answer (score 13):

I've just managed to solve this. I uninstalled the problem font via a font management program called [NexusFont](http://www.xiles.net/nexusfont/) but I think it will probably work with other programs with a similar functionality.

Comment: Wow this worked brilliantly for me and I was crazy about it. Spent a while in safe mode/ trying unlocker etc etc but this worked like a charm.

Comment: I've been using NexusFont for a while for font viewing, but never realized it would solve this problem as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

[matt wilkie's solution](https://superuser.com/a/264128) works. There's an even easier way in Windows 8, though. Simply open an elevated command prompt as administrator and enter the following command:

```
del /f /s /q /a "C:\Windows\fonts\my-font.ttf"
```

That will force delete the file and that's it. Please also note, that a restart might be required after editing it if the font doesn't work (mostly due to the confusion with font families if you have multiple types of the same font)

Comment: This worked but ensure you use CMD not Powershell with elevated administrator rights.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, if you still can't delete fonts because windows says they are in use, then boot to safe mode with only the command window.  cd to c:\Windows\Fonts and delete the fonts directly from here. This worked like a champ.  Note that you will need to note the file names of the fonts you want to delete before you reboot to safe mode.

Comment: Georgie Casey already said to use Safe Mode [in august](http://superuser.com/a/464512/16966), albeit even then some were still in use.

Comment: @mattwilkie Safe Mode is not Safe Mode Command Prompt. The virtue of Safe Mode Command Prompt is that many processes that might open fonts, such as Windows Explorer, do not start. The only more effective way to avoid open files is Recovery Shell.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it will work always

Comment: @Gusman ...after you identify the correct filename(s) for the fonts you need to delete yes this will always work.

Answer (score 2):

I just started [Windows 7 in Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Start-your-computer-in-safe-mode) and deleted the fonts then. Worked fine with no file in use error.

edit: turned out i got the file in use error in safe mode on some files! so i loaded up Cygwin in safe mode and deleted there. Worked.

Comment: Also see @MetaEd's comment to other answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/516022/16966), about using _Safe Mode Command Prompt_, not just Safe Mode.

Answer (score 1):

When I had this problem it was the Windows font Control Panel that was actually using the font.

All I needed to do was open the "Organise" menu, "Layout" submenu and untick "Details pane". I was now able to delete the font.

I'm using Windows 10 Creators Update, but the Control Panel looks the same as the Windows 7 version. If this works for anyone using Windows 7 or 8 please can you comment and I'll update the answer.