# How do I determine what process is using a font?

Tags: windows, fonts, csrss.exe

Sometimes when I delete a font through the control panel applet I get a message that it is in use. If I attempt to delete the file in `%SYSTEMROOT%\fonts` with [farmanager](http://farmanager.com) it says that its locked by csrss.exe, the windows subsystem process. Obviously, there is some sort of IPC going on between csrss.exe and the process that actualyl uses the font. My question is how do I determine what process has a lock on the font?

Comment: We already have a [older topic](http://superuser.com/questions/264072/cant-remove-certain-fonts-in-windows-7) where it's explained how to remove certain fonts that can't be deleted normally as they are in use.

Comment: @Justin This question wants to identify the process using the fonts, not just to remove them

Comment: @tog If you look in the body of the allgeded duplicate, they wish to identify the process causing the lock as well.

Comment: @justin maybe I'm being obtuse but I don't see a method of identifying the process and the question is marked as answered so it's unlikely to anytime in the future

Comment: @Tog: Considering that it was the OP himself who marked his own question as a duplicate, perhaps we should defer to him? After all, I doubt he's all that interested in identifying the process, just as long as he can delete the font somehow. If none of the answers on the dupe help him then perhaps identification might make sense to see if the process can be (forcibly) terminated.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/

Unlocker will tell you what is using it.  Allow you to unlock, and then rename, move, or delete it.  It may require a reboot, but it usually does not.

Comment: Firefox says this is malware/phishing

Comment: @beppe9000  Well,unlocker is not malware.  It is just because of the crazy things it does to unlock a file that it generates a false positive.

Comment: Uhm.. I had a look: the warning is probably is due to the quantity of complimentary adware that both the website and the setup offer.