# Certain web fonts being replaced by random font from fonts folder

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-10, fonts, web

I'm running into an issue involving certain fonts being replaced by (seemingly) random fonts in the Windows fonts folder. This only appears to happen on websites with custom fonts in use, or custom formatting. E.g. only certain subreddits are effected, whilst others are not. The issue occurs in all browsers and remained after a complete uninstall/reinstall of Chrome.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

[image: Messed up fonts on Giant Bomb]

[image: Messed up fonts on Giant Bomb after deleting previous font from Windows]

I've tried deleting the fonts in question (not default Windows fonts) using command line method detailed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/264072/cant-remove-certain-fonts-in-windows-7). This only resulted in a different font taking its place.

I also tried resetting Chrome's default font, and Chrome's settings generally, including the flushing out of cached images, files, cookies, etc.

Anyone know what might be going on here, and of any troubleshooting steps I can try, or a possible solution? Please help... These 1999 font choices are killing me.

**Update 24th May 2016 12:07 AM**

I was able to temporarily remedy the issue by adding this to the "Stylish" Chrome extension:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'helvetica neue';
    src: local('Arial');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'helvetica neue';
    font-weight: bold;
    src: local('Arial');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'helvetica';
    src: local('Arial');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'helvetica';
    font-weight: bold;
    src: local('Arial');
}
```

Does this offer up any clues as to how I might permanently remedy this issue?

Comment: It is possible that you'll see some font-related error message in the [console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).

Comment: No error messages in the console!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to remedy this issue by removing all traces of Helvetica from [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts] using regedit.exe and then logging out and back in again. Phew!