# a virus change wingdings font in XP i cant see anything in display setting in control panel

Tags: windows, windows-xp, virus

A PC with Windows XP yesterday take my time to repair.

first of all i search and googling and visit the results that a virus change the theme in Display (Control panel)
[image: Windows XP virus change every thing in theme in Display (Control panel)]

**step 1** : i delete the wing dings fonts and restart it.

then everything ok. and windows use default font and i can change the default theme.(**step 2**)

[image: change the default theme in windows xp]

he restore back in restore point and call me and request to repair again but remotely.

my question is how can i create and send batch script file for him.

**step 2** : to edit registry or is there any cmd command that i can send it by email?

Comment: The top looks like XP. The bottom... is that a LXDE swift? In fact, none of the bottom image looks like XP

Comment: i cant print screen from that PC so google and find pic close to my opinion so i change it now please focus on answer my friend! @JourneymanGeek

Comment: @JourneymanGeek that is XP in classic theme.

Comment: You could send that script by email but he would have to execute it himself.

Comment: @seth this is closer than i request him to install teamviewer or tell him to give me remote desktop

Comment: @echo_salik take a look at the review history.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek my bad... sorry :D

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi I agree with seth you should do this by TeamViewer. Sending a batch file what is to be run as Admin over internet does not sound safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what you need is a script, then this is what you need.

For First Part: https://superuser.com/a/963253/278336

```
del /f /s /q /a "C:\Windows\fonts\my-font.ttf"
```

For Second Part: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4882301/1444181

```
rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL %SystemRoot%\system32\desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:"C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\aero.theme"
```

You need to know the theme location and the theme name for this command.

Create a batch file and run as Admin. I dont remember XP folder structure, but you might as you recently played with it.

Have fun!

BTW: if the guy restored to an older point, he may have restored the virus too. Just saying.

Comment: how about step 2 how to set theme with command line. after Delete font?

Comment: let me search that. I'll update the answer

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi I have updated the answer

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi I'm glad i could help out :)